# SQL tricky query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, not-exists

I have this query

```
select lab.IDLAB,
       lab.NOMLAB,
       lab.CAPACIDAD
  from laboratorio lab 
 inner join DETALLESOLICITUD det on det.IDLAB = lab.IDLAB
 inner join dia on dia.iddia = det.iddia 
 inner join bloque blo on blo.idbloque = det.idbloque 
 inner join solicitud sol on sol.IDSOLICITUD=det.IDSOLICITUD
 where blo.idbloque = 1 
   and dia.iddia = 1
   and sol.estado in (1,2)
```

which returns:

```
 IDLAB | NOMLAB | CAPACIDAD
----------------------------
 1     | LCOMP1 | 22
```

And it does exactly what I want it to do. Now I want to get all the records from the table laboratorios that doesn't appear in this query. For example my `laboratorios` table has contents:

```
 IDLAB | NOMLAB | CAPACIDAD
----------------------------
 1     | LCOMP1 | 22
 2     | LCOMP2 | 31
 3     | LCOMP3 | 17
 4     | LCOMP4 | 26
```

And I want the following output:

```
 IDLAB | NOMLAB | CAPACIDAD
----------------------------
 2     | LCOMP2 | 31
 3     | LCOMP3 | 17
 4     | LCOMP4 | 26
```

I tried with a `not exists` statement this way:

```
select *
  from laboratorio
 where not exists(
        select lab.idlab, lab.nomlab, lab.CAPACIDAD 
          from laboratorio lab
         inner join DETALLESOLICITUD det on det.idlab = lab.idlab
         inner join dia on dia.iddia = det.iddia 
         inner join bloque blo on blo.idbloque = det.idbloque
         inner join solicitud sol on sol.IDSOLICITUD = det.IDSOLICITUD
         where blo.idbloque = 1 
           and dia.iddia = 1
           and sol.estado in(1,2)
       );
```

and this way:

```
select *
  from laboratorio
 where not exists(
        select det.IDLAB
          from DETALLESOLICITUD det
         inner join dia on dia.iddia = det.iddia
         inner join bloque blo on blo.idbloque = det.idbloque 
         inner join solicitud sol on sol.IDSOLICITUD = det.IDSOLICITUD
         where blo.idbloque = 1
           and dia.iddia = 1
           and sol.estado in(1,2)
       );
```

but both returns nothing. Any help will be really appreciate.

Comment: Please post some data and your required output will be helpful to us!!

Comment: I made the edition @Tarun

Comment: Thank you for obliterating my edits which made your question more readable.

Comment: sorry @APC, I was asked about my expected output and then I saw that my edition was deleted so I rolled back. Probably I should have made the code parts more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sub-queries return rows.  You know that because of the first query.  But `where not exists` is only true when the sub-query returns *no rows*.  Check it out:

```
SQL> select * from dual
  2  /

D
-
X

SQL>  select * from dual
  2  where not exists (select * from dual
  3                    where dummy = 'X')
  4  /

no rows selected

SQL> select * from dual
  2  where not exists (select * from dual
  3                    where dummy = 'Y')
  4  /

D
-
X

SQL>
```

So what you need to do is correlate the outer query with the sub-query.  Easiest way to do this:

```
select * from laboratorio 
where (idlab, nomlab, CAPACIDAD)
       not in (select lab.idlab, lab.nomlab, lab.CAPACIDAD 
                from laboratorio lab 
                inner join DETALLESOLICITUD det on  det.idlab = lab.idlab
                inner join dia on dia.iddia = det.iddia 
                inner join bloque blo on blo.idbloque = det.idbloque 
                inner join solicitud sol on sol.IDSOLICITUD=det.IDSOLICITUD                    
                where blo.idbloque = 1 
                and dia.iddia = 1 
                and sol.estado in(1,2)
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from laboratorio lab1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
select 1 from laboratorio lab 
inner join DETALLESOLICITUD det on det.IDLAB = lab.IDLAB
inner join dia on dia.iddia = det.iddia inner join bloque blo on blo.idbloque = det.idbloque 
inner join solicitud sol on sol.IDSOLICITUD=det.IDSOLICITUD 
where blo.idbloque = 1 and dia.iddia = 1 and sol.estado in (1,2)
  AND lab1.rowid = lab.rowid)
```

Check this out. I think you did not join with the outer table.